# extension of smooth function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Assume we have a Riemannian manifold $M$ embedded isometrically in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (It may not be closed or open). Let $V(i)$ be a smooth orthonormal vector field on $M$ (which can be extended to a basis in $T(\mathbb{R}^n)$ at every point).
Given that a smooth function $f$ on $M$ can be extended to $\mathbb{R}^n$ smoothly (say, the extended function is $g$), can it be extended in a way such that gradient of $g$ lies in $TM$ for all points in $M$?

Comment: Why do you need to know? Which examples of M do you have in mind?

Comment: For M, I am taking the space of positive definite matrices. I have the Laplacian(Laplace beltrami operator) on it but it cant be extended to all of R^k(k=n^2). I want to know if it can be extended atleast for functions on M which can be extended to R^k.

Comment: A tubular neighborhood of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be identified with its normal bundle. Extend to the normal bundle by making $f$ constant on the fibres. Take a smooth cut-off some distance away from $M$.

Comment: @willie wong I dont think this should work since by this argument, any smooth function can be extended to R^n. It will work only for nicer manifolds.

Comment: What do you mean by "embedded"? As long as $M\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is a closed set, by Whitney extension theorem **any** smooth $f$ on $M$ extends to a smooth $\tilde{f}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. The manifold structure is not even necessary.

Comment: Also, what's the point of $V(i)$ in your question? Your question doesn't seem to concern it at all.

Comment: You can ignore the V(i). M may not be a closed set. By embedded, I mean isometrically embedded.

Comment: 1) If $V(i)$ is not needed, could you revise the question accordingly? 2) Could you explain what's wrong or lacking in Willie's answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: Take a spiral in $\mathbb R^2$ like $\mathbb R_{>0}\ni t\mapsto t.e^{it}$ with the induced metric, $g(x,y)=x$. You cannot change $g$ such that its gradient is tangent to the spiral: You have problems at 0.